# Hadoop seems to be partially installed

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, installation

I'm running OSX 10.8.4 with Java 6. I believe java is correctly installed and I followed http://blog.tundramonkey.com/2013/02/24/setting-up-hadoop-on-osx-mountain-lion to install hadoop (I already had homebrew installed, but a few warnings do show up with brewdoctor)

The author says to run:

```
$ jps
```

with expected output looking like:

```
49770 TaskTracker
49678 JobTracker
49430 NameNode
49522 DataNode
49615 SecondaryNameNode
49823 Jps
```

I get:

```
1443 Jps
1142 JobTracker
1079 SecondaryNameNode
```

(missing the TaskTracker, NameNode and DataNode). I figured I would still give the example job a test run:

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/hadoop-examples-*.jar pi 10 100
```

(version 1.2.1 in my case), but I get the following error:

```
Mkdirs failed to create /tmp.hadoop-myusername
```

I'm new to Hadoop and don't have a computer science background, but I would I would like to figure out a way around this so I can get started on some tutorials.

Thanks!

Comment: There can be multiple reasons why it is/isn't working, without the log files it won't be of much help. Check for errors/exceptions in the log files.

Comment: @PraveenSripati, I'm not sure how to do that, or what that entails...

Comment: You could check for the log files inside the **logs** directory under your $HADOOP_HOME(if you haven't changed the log location in the hadoop-env.sh file).